# Lambda Functions in C++

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a question about calling a lambda function as was described in SO Documentation.

```
int multiplier = 5;
auto timesFive = [multiplier](int a) { return a * multiplier; }; 
std::cout << timesFive(2); // Prints 10

multiplier = 15;
std::cout << timesFive(2); // Still prints 2*5 == 10
```

Why doesn't it print `2 * 15 = 30`?
Clearly, the value of multiplier is being modified and when the call to `timesFive` is made, it should pick updated value of `multiplier`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to **capture** not by *value*, but by *reference*:

Just use `&multiplier` instead of `multiplier`.

The SO Documentation on Lambda Functions you linked to said:

> `[]` is the **capture** list. By default, variables of the enclosing scope cannot be accessed by a lambda. **Capturing** a variable makes it accessible inside the lambda, either as a **copy** or as a **reference**. **Captured variables become a part of the lambda;** in contrast to function arguments, they do not have to be passed when calling the lambda.

```
int a = 0;                       // Define an integer variable
auto f = [a]()  { return a*9; }; // OK, 'a' is "captured" by value
auto f = [&a]() { return a++; }; // OK, 'a' is "captured" by reference
```

Answer (score 2):

`multiplier` is captured by value, so it's *copied* inside the closure object when the lambda function is created.

You can change the `multiplier` local to the external function however you like, the copy inside the closure will stay at whatever value it was when it was created.

The result you expected is what you would obtain if you captured `multiplier` *by reference*, i.e. specifying `&multiplier` inside the capture list. Notice that in this last case the responsibility of making sure that the lambda does not outlive the variable captured by reference is only yours; as long as your lambda is only local to its containing function it's all fine, but if you return it or store it somewhere else (for example in an `std::function` variable) and you call it after the parent function returned you get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Capture multiplier by reference:

```
auto timesFive = [&multiplier](int a) { return a * multiplier; };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int multiplier = 5;
auto timesFive = [&multiplier](int a)->int{
    return a*multiplier;
};
cout << timesFive(1) << "\n";
multiplier = 6;
cout << timesFive(2);
```

The multiplier needs to captured by reference.If you want to capture all the variables you can write

```
auto timesFive = [&](int  a){return a * multiplier};
```